# how to remove/replace column name with whitespaces of a spark dataframe read from parquet file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

The dataset I'm working on has whitespaces in its columns and I got struck while trying to rename spark dataframe column name. Tried almost all the solutions available in stackoverflow. Nothing seems to work.

**Note: The file must be a parquet file**.

**df.printSchema**

root
 `|-- Type: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- ID: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- Catg Name: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- Error Msg: string (nullable = true)`

**df.show()**
**Error:**

> warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Catg Name" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;

**Tried:**

```
df.select(df.col("Catg Name").alias("Catg_Name"))
```

and then **df.printSchema**

root
 `|-- Type: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- ID: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- Catg_Name: string (nullable = true)`
 `|-- Error_Msg: string (nullable = true)`

works well but when I use **df.show()** it throws the same error.

> warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Catg Name" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;

Comment: While doing df.select(df.col("Catg Name").alias("Catg_Name")), I can see you are only selecting but not assigning it back to the dataframe. Can you list the exact steps you tried?

Comment: it would be helpful if you show us how you created df

Comment: `val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("mypath/1_0_0.parquet") `
`df.printSchema`

`val df_new =  df.select(df.col("Catg Name").alias("Catg_Name")) ` 

`df_new.printSchema`

df_new: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Catg_Name: string]
root
 |-- Catg_Name: string (nullable = true)
`df_new.show()`

**org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Catg Name" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;**

Comment: @PradeepVasamsetti could you please let me know if you found any solution for this ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @PradeepVasamsetti were you able to solve this issue ? I am stuck with the same issue :(

Comment: No man. I gave up on this and changed the schema at DB level :(

Comment: I am having this issue too. I used this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60208669/5983841) to replace spaces but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

How about this idea by removing the spaces in column names and reassigning to Dataframe?

```
val df1 = df.toDF("col 1","col 2","col 3") // Dataframe with spaces in column names

val new_cols =  df1.columns.map(x => x.replaceAll(" ", "")) // new column names array with spaces removed

val df2 = df1.toDF(new_cols : _*) // df2 with new column names(spaces removed)
```

Comment: new_cols: Array[String] = Array(Type, timestamp, ID, CatgName, ErrorMsg)
df_new: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Type: string ... 4 more fields]  
**org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Catg Name" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;**

Comment: Are you facing issue if you create your dataframe similar to `df2` as in this solution? df2.show() will have column names without spaces.

Comment: Yes. When I do `df_new.show()`, which is `df2.show()` in your case, throws the error posted above. It still refers to `Catg Name` though I have changed the column name to `CatgName`.

Comment: Check the Array[String] new_cols data. It should have spaces replaced. Comment your new_cols array code line

Comment: new_cols: Array[String] = Array(Type, timestamp, ID, CatgName, ErrorMsg)  

`df2.show()`

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Catg Name" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;

Comment: The above code doesn't work. It appears to be an error in Spark read Parquet API. You can rename the columns, but, when you do a show, Spark still goes back to the older column names.