# Renaming a column when opening a Parquet file in Pyspark / AWS Glue makes all data null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a snappy.parquet file which I need to open as a DataFrame in spark, then upload to a database.
Two of the column names contain spaces (" ").
Using

```
emps = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=db_name, table_name=tbl_emps)
```

Gives and error - column names contain invalid characters.
Using

```
df_emps = spark.read.parquet(file)
for c in df_emps.columns:
   df_emps = df_emps.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace(" ", ""))
df_emps = spark.read.schema(df_emps.schema).parquet(file)
```

reads the file and creates the dataframe, but the two columns that contained spaces ar now null.

How can I read this file into a dataframe and retain the content of these fields?

Comment: `df_emps = spark.read.schema(df_emps.schema).parquet(file)` looks unnecessary to me. after line 3 the dataframe should be okay. In line 4, it nulled those columns because they no longer exist (they are renamed in df_emps.schema)

Comment: Without line 4 I still get the error:

Comment: An error was encountered:
'Attribute name "First Name" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\\n\\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;'

Comment: could you show the code for uploading to database? I don't see df_emps being used in your first code snippet.

Comment: It's not there because I haven't done it yet, because of the error.  I have been using an AWS Glue Dev Endpoint and Jupyter notebook.  I have the above code, then df_emps.show(), which show a dataframe with the two columns of Null.

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51197279

Comment: Yes, I've tried all of those.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AWS Glue, you can switch to using AWS Glue v4 which includes [Spark 3.3.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27442) where the issue was fixed.